# Are the followers on a blog publicly visible?

Tags: wordpress.com, followers

I've got a blog and I've got a few followers who's blog's are related to stuff I'd...rather not be associated to.

I know that I can't remove followers and that I can moderate the comments (I have a very strict Akismet setup going already and have to approve all comments, just to be safe) but I still would like to know if someone could find/view the list of followers. Is this possible, and if so, is there anything I can do about it? The followers I'm talking about are obviously those who follow a blog for the attention, as they followed, and then haven't done thing since.

I'm not hosting the blog myself, so I have limited control over what I can do with my blog.

Answer (score 1):

No, the list of followers of a WordPress.com blog is *not* made public.

It is visible only to the blog admin(s) under the "Site Stats" => "My Followers" section of the Dashboard.